# Batch File Error: "The string is missing the terminator: '. " for a Powershell Cmd

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file, format

### Background

I have a batch file that is running a PowerShell Script. I've added this batch file to the startup folder of approximately 60 windows computers which are running either the W7 or W10 OS. It runs successfully on 95% of the PCs. On the remaining 5%, the batch file doesn't run and the error that's outputted is shown below.

```
The string is missing the terminator '.
  + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

### Code

This is the code I've written on the batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

### Question

What can I do to fix this error and have the batch file run successfully on all computers?

Comment: The error message comes from Powershell. Are you sure the `Test.ps1` is correct on the computers that won't run it? How do you deploy the script, maybe there's old version there?

Comment: @vonPryz `Test.ps1` is correct and it works when I run it on every computer. I usually run `Test.ps1` using a shortcut, but when I tried copying the shortcut link to the startup folder as suggested by [Windows Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd), it works around half the time. Hence why I decided to use a batch file instead.

Comment: Does "works around half the time" mean that it succeeds and fails on same computer? Or that it works in half of the workstations OK, but fails on others?

Comment: @vonPryz Sorry for the confusion. It's the latter - It works on half the workstations OK and fails on others.